# Understanding RACSignal Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I'm currently taking my first steps in ReactiveCocoa and I experience some steep learning curve to understand the principals.

Anyway here's what I already came up with.

I bind a NSArray property to a RACSignal to be able to react to the incoming JSON data over network.

```
- (void)updateRandomUserData 
{
    @weakify(self);
    RAC(self, users) = [[self fetchRandomUserData] doNext:^(NSDictionary *json){
    @strongify(self);
    NSMutableArray *randomUsers = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSDictionary *dict in json[@"data"]) {
           BKRandomUser *randomUser = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[BKRandomUser class] fromJSONDictionary:dict error:nil];
           [randomUsers addObject:randomUser];
        }

        self.users = randomUsers;
    }];
}
```

The signal creation looks like this:

```
- (RACSignal *)fetchRandomUserData
{

    return [[RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {

      NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

      AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
      [subscriber sendNext:JSON];
      } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON, NSError *error) {
        [subscriber sendError:error];
      }];

      [operation start];

      return [RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{
          [operation cancel];
      }];

      }] doError:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error description]);
    }];
```

}

Now when the web service doesn't provide any data I want to react to this. Right now the app crashes with the following statement, which I honestly don't understand:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Received error from  name: [[+createSignal:] -doError:] -doNext: in binding for key path "users" on : (null)'

What am I missing here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The accepted answer will work around the problem, but there's a more idiomatic, elegant way to handle this:

First off, instead of using `-doNext:`, use `-map:` to transform your JSON into the array of users:

```
RAC(self, users) = [[self fetchRandomUserData] map:^(NSDictionary *json){
    NSMutableArray *randomUsers = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in json[@"data"]) {
       BKRandomUser *randomUser = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[BKRandomUser class] fromJSONDictionary:dict error:nil];
       [randomUsers addObject:randomUser];
    }

    return randomUsers;
}];
```

Then, to handle the error, you can use `-catch:`:

```
RAC(self, users) = [[[self fetchRandomUserData] map:^(NSDictionary *json){
    NSMutableArray *randomUsers = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in json[@"data"]) {
       BKRandomUser *randomUser = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[BKRandomUser class] fromJSONDictionary:dict error:nil];
       [randomUsers addObject:randomUser];
    }

    return randomUsers;
}] catch:^(NSError *error) {
    return [RACSignal return:@[]];
}];
```

In this example, if an error happens we catch it and replace it with an empty array. You could do whatever you wanted there. Replace it with `nil`, or `+[RACSignal empty]` if you just want to ignore the whole thing. Or call another method that returns a `RACSignal *`.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification and the additional explanation. That really helps a lot. A question that came up while reading your answer was how can I know whats best to use for a returning RAC Signal. So in this case what makes `-map:` more appropriate than `-doNext:`?

Comment: `-map:` takes each value from a signal and transforms it. That's why the block returns `id`. `-doNext:` doesn't return anything. It just gives you a change to peak into a signal.

Comment: What is it in this example that would throw an error and triggers `-catch`?

Comment: `-fetchRandomUserData` as defined in the original question sends an error when the JSON request fails.

Answer (score -4):

1. By writing `RAC(self, users)`, you means you want to binding the signal's return to the property `users`, but you are not returning anything in the signal handler.
2. You are using the `doNext`, which is a injection for current signal. You may want to subscribe it instead of injecting the side-effect.

Solve:

You can remove the `RAC(self, users)` binding if you want to assign it in the `subscribeNext` side-effect, so just subscribe for the signal would be OK for your case, like this:

```
@weakify(self);
[[self fetchRandomUserData] subscribeNext:^(NSDictionary *json) {
    @strongify(self);
    NSMutableArray *randomUsers = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in json[@"data"]) {
        BKRandomUser *randomUser = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[BKRandomUser class] fromJSONDictionary:dict error:nil];
        [randomUsers addObject:randomUser];
    }

    self.users = randomUsers;
}];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed that was the solution to catch the crash. I assumed that the signal handler is `doError:^(NSError *error)` block. Besides that I really have difficulties understanding all the different subscription options like `doNext`, `doCompleted`, `subscribeNext`... etc. ...

Comment: `doSomething` is a injection of current signal, that block would be executed before the corresponding signal sent out and the signal itself would flow as it (returning a new RACSignal). While the `subscribeSomething` method is intent to interact with the signal and it returns a RACDisposable